# Moodle dynamically load css file

Tags: moodle

I need to apply style sheet given by designer based on a property of $USER.

Can anyone guide as to how to dynamically load a css file,without including the css file in theme config $THEME->sheets ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is for a particular page, then you can use $PAGE->requires->css('/path/to/stylesheet.css') on that page to load the correct stylesheet for that page (must be done before the page output starts).

If you want this on every page and you're working within your theme, then you could override the core_renderer (to theme_MYTHEME_core_renderer), then override the __construct function to check the $USER global, then call $this->page->requires->css(...) to load the appropriate CSS.